# Server Status Code: 302 Found Tested value: 1 EXEC XP_

Tags: sql, sql-server, code-injection

I read lots of posts about SQL injections.

I understand a 302 code does not necessarily means the injection succeeded.

I changed my `header(loc ... )` into `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` and it indeed show me the attack failed. But I still get one line with the doubtful 302 code:

> Server Status Code: 302 Found Tested value:

I cannot not manage to find out what `1 EXEC XP_` is about

Could somebody help me understanding this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You question is very unclear. There are several XP stored procedures on MSSQL. Which one is the  1 EXEC XP_ referring to? What are you trying to achieve with your SQL inejection attack? Please clarify.

Comment: Well, I used FireFox SQL inject me to track the weaknesses of my script. The test result log show : ""Server Status Code: 302 Found Tested value:1 EXEC XP_"" 1) I do not know what it means 2) I havn't succeeded in avoiding this, although I changed my header(loc...) into a header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); to spot which code line is reposnsible for what . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar lot of testing using SQL inject me. I'm running a ubuntu box it still tells me that 1 EXEC XP_ worked but im not using MSSQL. I was trying to work out exactly why it is giving me 302 errors. I tried performing the injections by hand but the page seemed to output fine.

From what I can understand about 302 errors it appears to be something to do with redirection of pages, e.g if your php has a redirection after a user input values and sends off a form.
I think it is mistaking the redirection for a 302 error. or something along those lines.

Sorry I know that wasnt very clear but its what i was able to gather from my results.

Be greatly appreciated if someone could clear exactly what happening up.